# Database choice for crawled page semantics

Tags: database, web-crawler, in-memory-database, nosql

I'm not sure whether this question has already been asked in the past. 
I'm writing a webcrawler, intended to extract information from multiple websites for promotions,prices and product descriptions.

Which database choice would be ideal to do an in memory comparison on the data of promotions and prices, based on identification of the same product from multiple websites.

I know the design is going to be complex for the Scraper, HTMLDataProcessor and Storage for wrangling. But, I'm looking for a solve for the data layer choice.

Appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest first you create your object model or Entity relationship diagram for all the entities.(a.k.a ER diagram)

For instance you can see the tutorial here: http://creately.com/blog/diagrams/er-diagrams-tutorial/

Once you have the diagram and relationships between your entity then you can make a choice of whether you need relational database or not.

You need to answer question like:

1. Do you care about FK (foreign key) constraints?
2. What is the most common query and do you care about it's performance?
3. Is an in-memory database sufficient or do you need data to be persisted?

Think along those lines.

Comment: i made a choice of ElasticSearch.